# Copy Files using batch Script with a particular naming requirement

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a batch script which will copy all the files from directories and sub directories to a particular location with a special name.

I created a list using which I am trying to copy the files

contents of List.txt

```
D:\HOST\subdir1\1111.txt
D:\HOST\subdir2\2222.txt
D:\HOST\subdir3\3333.txt
D:\HOST\subdir3\34rf.pdf
D:\HOST\subdir4\4444.txt
D:\HOST\subdir5\5555.txt
D:\HOST\subdir5\5tg.xls
D:\HOST\subdir5\subdir_55\007.xlsx
```

The target folder should contain the files as:

```
subdir1_1111.txt
subdir2_2222.txt
subdir3_3333.txt
subdir3_34rf.pdf
subdir1_1111.txt
.
.
subdir5_007.xlsx
```

Here HOST,subdir1 to subdir 5  and subdir_55 all are subdirectories.

The code which iam trying to use is given below:

```
@echo off & setlocal
cd %~dp0

IF EXIST list.txt del /F list.txt
cd %~dp0\HOST
dir /b /a-d /s *.* >> %~dp0\list.txt
cd..

for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=\" %%a in (%~dp0\list.txt) do copy /b     %~dp0\HOST\%%c\%%d %~dp0\TARGET\%%c_%%d
```

The above code only works when there are no sub directories inside subdir1 to subdir5. What my requirement want is that it should copy the files if there are n number of sub directories also. Another thing i am not sure how to handle the sub directory names with space.

I know it will not work with tokens because there can be "n" number of tokens as there might be "n" number of sub directories inside the main subdir.

Kindly help me.

Comment: [The Windows command prompt (cmd) is not MS-DOS!!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend *not* to use `for /F` and delimiters to do path manipulations, use the [`~` modifiers](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) of `for` variables instead.

I would do it like this:

- iterate through your source root directory to retrieve all the names of the immediate sub-directories, using a `for /D` loop;
- for each sub-directory, gather all files recursively by a `for /R` loop;
- build every final target file name;

Here is the code:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SOURCE=D:\HOST"   & rem // (source root directory)
set "_TARGET=D:\TARGET" & rem // (target root directory)
set "_DIRPATT=*"        & rem // (pattern for names of immediate sub-directories)
set "_FILPATT=*.*"      & rem // (pattern for names of files to copy)
set "_SEPAR=_"          & rem // (separator character to build new file names)

rem // Walk through immediate sub-directories of source root directory:
for /D %%D in ("%_SOURCE%\%_DIRPATT%") do (
    rem /* Process each immediate sub-directory in a sub-routine;
    rem    `%%~fD` is the full path to the current sub-directory;
    rem    its pure name will be derived in the sub-routine: */
    call :PROCESS "%%~fD" "%_FILPATT%" "%_TARGET%"
)

endlocal
exit /B


:PROCESS  val_directory  val_pattern  val_target
rem /* Sub-routine to process a single sub-directory. Arguments:
rem    val_directory   [%~1]  sub-directory to process;
rem    val_pattern     [%~2]  pattern for file names;
rem    val_target      [%~3]  target directory; */
rem // Retrieve all files in the sub-directory recursively:
for /R "%~1" %%F in ("%~2") do (
    rem /* Build target file path; `%~n1` is the base name of the sub-directory,
    rem    `%%~nxF` is the full name of the currently iterated file;
    rem    then check whether the target file already exists: */
    if not exist "%~3\%~n1%_SEPAR%%%~nxF" (
        rem /* Target file does not exist, so copy the file;
        rem    `%%~fF` is the full path of the currently iterated source file: */
        copy /Y "%%~fF" "%~3\%~n1%_SEPAR%%%~nxF"
    )
)
exit /B
```

If a target file already exists, it will not be overwritten; if you do want to overwrite in such cases, simply remove the `if not exist` query around the `copy` command line.

Comment: Aschipfl... I am so sorry that somehow I missed thanking you for the effort you put for me... So even if it's after 4 long years... Thank you so much for answering. I hope you and your family are doing well.. i pray to god for your well-being... take care and thanks once again.